# Can't find split() method or replacement in string module in python 3.4.1?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split, attributeerror

I'm trying some text manipulation stuff out and am bumping into the error:

```
wordlist = string.split(" ")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I have imported the string module like so:

```
import string
```

When I list the methods available in the string module, split() is not there as expected.

```
['ChainMap', 'Formatter', 'Template', '_TemplateMetaclass', '__builtins__', 
'__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', 
'__spec__', '_re', '_string', 'ascii_letters', 'ascii_lowercase', 'ascii_uppercase',
'capwords', 'digits', 'hexdigits', 'octdigits', 'printable', 'punctuation', 
'whitespace']
```

I'm not sure if this is an error on my end, or if there is a new method for split. How do I split my strings via the whitespace between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont have to import the string module for splitting. You can simply run a split on your string variable

```
str = "testing 1 2 3"
print str.split(" ") #or str.split()
```

**output**

```
['testing', '1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: In python 2 I did from string import split
In python 3 I'm lazy so I did  split = lambda a,b: a.split(b)

Answer (score 1):

string.split is deprecated in 2.x and gone in 3.x.

Just do:

```
yourStringName.split(' ')
```

With reference to [string.split error? python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964144/string-split-error-python)